# "argc, argv" missing in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

When I create new project in Code::Blocks in main.c `int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )` is missing. Instead, the signature for main.c is built like this: `int main()`. How I can change this?

Comment: Have you attempted to manually restore the signature?

Comment: Maybe the laziest programmer/question I've ever seen.

Comment: nonetheless a valid question imho that does not deserve negative voting

Comment: Voting not to close, because changing the `main()` prototype from a template seems not too localized to me.

Comment: I have to agree with Seki, despite the hard-to-parse double double-negative :-) This is very much a tool commonly used by programmers as per the FAQ, and it seems to me that getting a canonical `main` would be important to a lot of people so I'm not sure why everyone's closing as too localised.

Answer (score 6):

Wizards in Code::Blocks are Squirrel scripts so you can right click on the template and choose `Edit script`.

See [here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Wizard_scripts) for details on editing or creating new wizards.

Another option is to change the actual `main.c` file to introduce the changes. For example, under Debian, the `main.c` template file is stored in the directory

```
/usr/share/codeblocks/templates/wizard/console/c
```

and you can just edit that.

Alternatively, you can create your basic project, modify the source code as you want it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return 0;
}
```

and then use `File` menu, `Save project as template` to create a user template.